# why does ffmpeg export black video?

Tags: ffmpeg, encoder

i give ffmpeg a simple task which is the following

ffmpeg -i test.avi -c:v rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p out.yuv

i try to play the video but it gives a black screen, even in a .yuv player.
[ffmpeg supposedly "running"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7ZnQ.png)

is there some human error that i am doing, or is it just a piece of shit encoder coded by incompetent people.

Signed
Slingring

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg` is doing exactly what you told it to do. You are outputting raw video. This has no header, so no info is there to tell the player about the video attributes. You have to provide the player the correct attributes.

Example using `ffplay`:

```
ffplay -f rawvideo -video_size 320x240 -framerate 30 -pixel_format yuv420p video.yuv
```

See the [FFmpeg rawvideo demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#rawvideo) documentation.